# I have a query to select data on 3 conditions however need to insert an extra clause to select only a specific month

Tags: sql, sql-server

My `[date created]` data is in the following format  04/08/2017 20:06:14. my query below returns data for all dates in the table however i need the data only for the previous month but am unsure how to convert my date/time and also where to insert the extra where clause in the code.

```sql
SELECT r1.requestId,
       r1.memberID,
       r1.department,
       r1.[Date Created],
       r1.scheme
FROM Requests r1
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT COUNT()
     FROM requests r2
     WHERE r2.memberId = r1. memberId
       AND r2.department = r1.department
       AND r2.[Date Created] = r1.[Date Created]
     GROUP BY r2.memberId,r2.departmetId,r2.[Date Created]
     HAVING COUNT() > 3)
```

Comment: Not sure about the details from your question.  What type of field is `Date Created`?  If it's a date field then it's not really in a format, it's just displayed that way by whatever tool you're using to query it.  If it's a character field then you're doing it wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

how about just adding another condition in the WHERE-Clause:

```
SELECT r1.requestId,
       r1.memberID,
       r1.department,
       r1.[Date Created],
       r1.scheme
FROM Requests r1
WHERE EXISTS
        (SELECT COUNT()
         FROM requests r2
         WHERE r2.memberId = r1. memberId
           AND r2.department = r1.department
           AND r2.[Date Created] = r1.[Date Created]
         GROUP BY r2.memberId,r2.departmetId,r2.[Date Created]
         HAVING COUNT() > 3)
  AND r1.[Date Created] BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0)   --First day of previous month
                            AND DATEADD(SECOND,-1, DATEADD(DAY,1,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1))) --Last Day of previous month
```

Comment: Might not want to use a `between` for this, just use >= 1rst of previous month and < 1rst of current month.  Unless you want to spend hours researching a discrepancy your accounting department finds in the reports when a request comes in at `23:59:59.237` and it doesn't show up on either month...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the below query , it may help

```
SELECT r1.requestId,
   r1.memberID,
   r1.department,
   r1.[Date Created],
   r1.scheme
FROM Requests r1

where 

( 
  Year(r1.[Date Created])*12 + MONTH(r1.[Date Created]) = YEAR(getdate())+Month(Getdate()) 
)
and
count(*) over(partition by r1.memberId,r1.department,r1.[Date Created])>3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a normal `DATETIME` field I like the trick of using `DATEDIFF` to compare by month.  Try adding this to your where clause (your question is unclear on if you want to compare the dates in your outer query or subquery):

```
AND DATEDIFF(month, 0, r1.[Date Created]) = DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()) - 1
```

This compares the number of months from `1/1/1900`